# How to change the color of div while a radio input is selected using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

The current problem I am having is that when an input is selected, all the div elements are permanently changed to red. I only want the selected input's div to become red. Also, if another input is selected I want the previous input to return to its original color.

This is what I have so far,
CodePen: https://codepen.io/martinlutherwinn/pen/jOEVmGj

```js
function chgCol() {
    var input =[];
    var input = document.getElementsByClassName("Amt_Int");
    var div =[];
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName("Amt_Lal");
    
    for(i=0; i < input.length; i++){
        for(i=0; i < div.length; i++){
            
          if(input[i].checked = true){
            div[i].style.color = "red"; 
            div[i].style.borderColor= "red";
            } else{
                div[i].style.color = "blue"; 
                div[i].style.borderColor= "blue";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.DoF_Amt, .Pel_Info,.Pat_Info{
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;  
    color:blue;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    padding: 5%   
}
.Amt_Cor{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.Amt_Lal{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    border: .3vmin solid rgba(0,0,255,1);
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 2%;
    height: 10vmin;
    width: 10vmin;
    font-size: 4vmin;
    margin: 2%;
}
.Amt_Int{
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="DoF_Amt">
  <h2>Donation Amount</h2>
  <div class="Amt_Cor">
    <div class="Amt_Lal">
      <label>
        <input class="Amt_Int" type="radio" name="amount" value="one" />$1
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="Amt_Lal" onclick="chgCol()">
      <label>
        <input
          class="Amt_Int"
          type="radio"
          name="amount"
          value="twentyfive"
        />$25
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="Amt_Lal" onclick="chgCol()">
      <label>
        <input class="Amt_Int" type="radio" name="amount" value="fifty" />$50
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="Amt_Lal" onclick="chgCol()">
      <label>
        <input
          class="Amt_Int"
          type="radio"
          name="amount"
          value="seventhyfive"
        />$75
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="Amt_Lal" onclick="chgCol()">
      <label>
        <input
          class="Amt_Int"
          type="radio"
          name="amount"
          value="Custom"
        />Custom
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="/JavaScript/selectedInput.js"></script>
  <button type="button">Donate with PayPal</button>
  <button type="button">Donate with a Card</button>
</form>
```

Comment: in the javascript section by  **input[i].checked = true**   you are making that inputs check value true. use **===** to compare with true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the event-target along to your click-handler by changing `onclick="chgCol()"` to `onclick="chgCol({ target })"`. Then you can react more dynamically.

An even better solution would be to delegate the event to the parent-element (`<div class="Amt_Cor">`). An example follows:

```js
const [clickTarget] = document.getElementsByClassName('Amt_Cor');

clickTarget.onclick = ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.classList.contains('Amt_Lal')) return;
  const currentlyHighlighted = document.querySelector('.highlight');
  if (currentlyHighlighted) currentlyHighlighted.classList.remove('highlight');
  target.classList.add('highlight');
  target.firstElementChild.checked = true;
  console.log(document.querySelector('[name="amount"]:checked').value);
};
```

```css
.DoF_Amt, .Pel_Info,.Pat_Info{
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;  
    color:blue;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    padding: 5%   
}
.Amt_Cor{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.Amt_Lal{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    border: .3vmin solid rgba(0,0,255,1);
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 2%;
    height: 10vmin;
    width: 10vmin;
    font-size: 4vmin;
    margin: 2%;
}
.Amt_Lal::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 15vmin;
  height: 15vmin;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.Amt_Int {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    border: 0;
}
.highlight {
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Amt_Cor">  
  <label class="Amt_Lal">
    <input class="Amt_Int" type="radio" name="amount" value="one">$1
  </label>
  <label class="Amt_Lal">
    <input class="Amt_Int" type="radio" name="amount" value="twentyfive">$25
  </label>
  <label class="Amt_Lal">
    <input class="Amt_Int" type="radio" name="amount" value="fifty">$50
  </label>
  <label class="Amt_Lal">
    <input class="Amt_Int" type="radio" name="amount" value="seventhyfive">$75
  </label>
  <label class="Amt_Lal">
    <input class="Amt_Int" type="radio" name="amount" value="Custom">Custom
  </label>                  
</div>
```

Comment: I feel like I should point out that in this example, you can select the `div` and change its colour without actually changing which `input` is selected -- I have $25's button selected but the $75 `div` is red. That's gonna cause some problems if he ends up hiding the radio buttons like he did in his OP.

Comment: @matthew-e-brown you can't anymore. Good catch!

Comment: @AndreNuechter I noticed in your last if statement there are no curly brackets. Is there a reason for that? I tried adding curly brackets and when I did, the code didn't work.

Comment: @Martin I only want to remove the class from the element, if it exists to prevent an error (_optional chaining_ would be great here;) and in JavaScript curly braces around single line conditionals are optional.

Comment: @AndreNuechter I edited the code a bit so I could understand it better. However, yet again, I seem to be missing something. Could you take a look at the Javascript and see what is causing the issue? It would be greatly appreciated! Here is the CodePen: https://codepen.io/martinlutherwinn/pen/qBEmKBw.

Comment: @Martin You need to move the line where you set the highlight to the clicked element out of the if-clause as you want that to happen no matter what.

Comment: @AndreNuechter omg, I just figured it out(It works now), thank you, Andre

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with Pure CSS if you restructured your DOM a little and used the labels as the bubbles instead of their parent `div`s. You can take advantage of the `:checked` selector alongside the `+` (adjacent sibling) selectors.

Here's my take:

```css
/* The important stuff: */

label {
  border: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
}

input:checked+label {
  border: .1rem solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

/* The rest: */

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input id="option1" type="radio" name="amount" value="1">
    <label for="option1">$1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="option2" type="radio" name="amount" value="5">
    <label for="option2">$5</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="option3" type="radio" name="amount" value="25">
    <label for="option3">$25</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="option4" type="radio" name="amount" value="50">
    <label for="option4">$50</label>
  </div>
</form>
```